# Xamarin - Android - OneSignal - Handle User tap notification when app is terminated

Tags: android, xamarin, onesignal

I am building an Android App with Xamarin.

The App receives Push notifications via OneSignal.

I have a problem with handling user tap on notification when the app has been swiped away.

When the user taps the notification the MainPage is starting but I need to navigate the user to the details page.

I have implemented NotificationExtenderService to handle the push messages received when the app is terminated but I can't figure out how to handle the tap event.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could navigate to the specific page you want after the application opens the MainPage.Set a Boolean tag in MainPage, mark it true when you receive a notification, and navigate to a specific page.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT thank you for your reply. The problem with this is if I just set the tag to true with every received notification, I will be not able to tell if the the user actually clicked on it or just open the app.

Comment: You could custom a local notification when you receive the notificaiton,refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100056/how-to-open-a-different-xaml-page-on-push-notification-click-event.